# How to remove duplicate values in array?

Tags: php

I tried many ways, I have an array:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(113) "23138,19031,22951,22951,22962,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858" }
```

Tried:

```
$a = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $a)));
var_dump($a);
```

Or

```
$a = array_unique($a);
var_dump($a);
```

And

```
$a = array_values(array_unique($a));
var_dump($a);
```

Nothing, I still get duplicated values, the full code would be:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$postid = $post->ID;
$userPosts= get_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', TRUE );
$userPosts = str_replace(' ', '', $userPosts);
$a = explode(', ', $userPosts);
$a = array_values(array_unique($a));
var_dump($a);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $a );
```

Comment: Why down votes?

Comment: Think in steps. First, you need it as array, split on the comma: Explode. And not you want unique values: array_unique() -> `$array = array_unique( explode("," $string) );`

Comment: You have an array containing one item, which is a string. Not an array with multiple items.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe because this sounds like it has been answered a lot. Also, with some effort you could have found [array_unique()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on PHPs manual

Comment: @kerbholz maybe with some effort you would have noticed I have used unique as per the question code

Comment: Didn't read your code

Comment: `$userPosts = str_replace(' ', '', $userPosts);
$a = explode(', ', $userPosts);` you remove spaces then you try to explode with *comma space* but there are no spaces, you just removed them, so the output should be one item. One long string that you try to remove duplicates from. This should be cought if you had done proper debugging

Comment: @Andreas damn yes, you're correct. Thanks. Paste that into an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$userPosts = str_replace(' ', '', $userPosts);
$a = explode(', ', $userPosts);
```

You remove spaces then you try to explode with `comma space` but there are no spaces, you just removed them, so the output should be one item.
One long string that you try to remove duplicates from which does not work.

Two possible solutions remove the removal of spaces.
Or remove the space from explode.

I would advice to remove the removal of spaces as it's probably not needed, thus just using CPU for nothing.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$postid = $post->ID;
$userPosts= get_user_meta($user_id, 'save_post', TRUE );
$a = explode(', ', $userPosts);
$a = array_values(array_unique($a));
var_dump($a);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $a );
```

EDIT from comments it seems there are no spaces in `$userPosts` so the working solution is to remove the space from the explode.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$postid = $post->ID;
$userPosts= get_user_meta($user_id, 'save_post', TRUE );
$a = explode(',', $userPosts);
$a = array_values(array_unique($a));
var_dump($a);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $a );
```

Comment: i still get duplicated values tho, when i do  `var_dump($a); ` i get: `array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "20504,20486,20486" }`

Comment: $userPosts Does it include spaces or not. Your code indicates yes, but now your comment says "probably not". If there is no spaces, make `$a = explode(', ', $userPosts);` to: `$a = explode(',', $userPosts);`

Comment: ok works with no spaces, thanks. Accepting, yet update the answer with no space pls

Comment: Not you but your var_dump whisperd gently in my ears "probably not". Didn't you hear it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should use `explode()` to build an array from your string first:

```
$x = "23138,19031,22951,22951,22962,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858";
print_r(array_unique(explode(',', $x)));
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => 23138
    [1] => 19031
    [2] => 22951
    [4] => 22962
    [5] => 18858
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains only one value: the string `"23138,19031,22951,22951,22962,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858"`.

You have to split this string into pieces using the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function then pass its result to [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove the duplicates:

```
$input = array("23138,19031,22951,22951,22962,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858,18858");

$pieces = explode(',', $input[0]);
$noDups = array_unique($pieces);

// Check the outcome
print_r($noDups);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 23138
    [1] => 19031
    [2] => 22951
    [4] => 22962
    [5] => 18858
)
```

If you need the values back in a string (separated by comma) you can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).